# How to generate war package to run on a Tomcat? Using Gradle and Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat, web-applications

I would like to know,
I have a web application with springmvc and springboot. I use gradle.
I need to generate a web package that runs on a tomcat server, I need to generate a war package that will not run as a SpringBoot application.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I solved it.
I followed this documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-traditional-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You could use **gradle eclipse** command and then -once imported to eclipse- export it as a **warfile**.